# How we can merge arrays with uniq values using Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

If i've two array like

```
a= [{ name: 'a', name: 'b' }] 
b= [c, d, b, e]
```

I want the result to be like

```
[
    { 'name': 'a' },
    { 'name': 'b' },
    { 'name': 'c' },
    { 'name': 'd' },
    { 'name': 'e' }
]
```

But do not want to repeatedly check like first array convert using `_.map()` and after merge using `_.union()` or other type then check `_.uniq()` through but I need all if possible then make as a short layer.

Comment: please add valid data with only one same key.

Comment: No, i have data like that and need to merge in which i want in format.

Comment: no you can not. even if you try, you get the last value, not two properties.

Comment: But i can do it but it's not right it's make more for that...

Comment: So, you just help me like if you try to make collection in backbone as uniq then how you can check it and prevent it ??

Comment: The data in your question is invalid syntax and your description is really hard to follow, please take the time to provide valid data and a clear description of the expected behaviour.

Comment: `{ name: 'a', name: 'b' }` This is not possible. You can't have the same key twice on the same object.  What does your data *actually* look like?

Answer (score 0):

To do this with Backbone.Collection, you can leverage the [model parse function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) as well as providing the `parse: true` option on instantiation. By specifying a [model `idAttribute`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute), duplicate models are avoided. Note: I used lodash here for some type checking and array merge.

```js
var a = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}];
var b = ['c', 'd', 'b', 'e'];
var Coll = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'name',
    parse: function(resp, opts) {
      var modelData = resp;
      if (_.isString(resp)) {
        modelData = { name: resp };
      }
      return modelData;
    }
  })
});
// then on initialize
var data = _.union(a, b);
var coll = new Coll(data, {parse: true});
console.log(JSON.stringify(coll.toJSON()));
// yields
"[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"d"},{"name":"e"}]"

// alternatively, you can choose not merge the data to start
// and instead either pass some at initialize and then
// some with a coll.set later, or all with set
// Note: set call still needs parse:true as well as remove:false
var coll = new Coll(a, {parse: true});
coll.set(b, {parse: true, remove: false});
console.log(JSON.stringify(coll.toJSON()));
// yields
"[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"d"},{"name":"e"}]"
```